# My solution for AngularJS app of clearing IE cache works but it creates a notification in templateCache not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an app that had the following problem:

Using internet explorer, when I change a value in my webpage and press submit, it writes it to the database just fine, however, when I press F5 it shows the previous value that was there before I changed it.

This is an angularJS app testing it in IE 11.

This solution works

```
   if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
    }
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Pragma = 'no-cache';
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
  }
```

However, the webapp has a button used for notifications that is now disabled because it is using $templateCache to put the data to a page that is created dynamically

any ideas?

Comment: So I ended up finding an answer that worked.  If you put the following line of code `document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache');`  inside of your app.module.js wrapped around a `.config(<function name>)`, it will disable a portion of this weird caching behavior without it messing up your $templateCache.